# Trouble figuring out the UITableViewCell multiline ability

Tags: iphone, dynamic, uitableview, multiline

Got pretty far with this one but am hanging on the part where I read out the string information.

I made a cell that receives data from an external xml file, it all works fine but some cell contain to much text which I want to display over multiple lines. Also no problem. But the tricky part is the dynamic height of my cell. I configured this in the heightForRowAtIndexPath: method, but I need to know the amount of text(rows) the cell contains, and I am stuck on the part how to connect that to my cellText(string) variable.
Any help would be welcome :-)

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    }

    // Set the text in the cell for the section/row.
    NSString *endDate = [XMLParser stringFromDate:[XMLParser dateFromString:stage.end]];
    int endDateLength = endDate.length;
    NSString *endTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [endDate substringFromIndex:endDateLength -7]];

    NSString *startDate = [XMLParser stringFromDate:[XMLParser dateFromString:stage.start]];
    int startDateLength = startDate.length;
    NSString *startTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [startDate substringFromIndex:startDateLength -7]];

    NSString *date = [XMLParser stringFromDate:[XMLParser dateFromString:stage.start]];
    int dateLength = date.length;
    NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [date substringToIndex:dateLength -7]];

    NSString *cellText = nil;
    NSString *cellExplainText = nil;

    //Pre title arrays
    dateTitleArray      = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Dag", @"Start tijd", @"Eind tijd", nil];
    nameTitleArray      = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Naam", @"Graad",nil];
    addressTitleArray   = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Dojo", @"Straat", @"Plaats",nil];
    infoTitleArray      = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Kosten", @"Contact", @"Details", nil];

    dateArray           = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: dateString, startTime, endTime, nil];
    nameArray           = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: stage.teacher, stage.grade, nil];
    addressArray        = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: stage.dojo, stage.street, stage.city, nil];
    infoArray           = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: stage.cost, stage.contact, stage.details, nil];

    switch (indexPath.section)
    {
        case 0:
            cellExplainText = [dateTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cellText        = [dateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            break;
        case 1:
            cellExplainText = [nameTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cellText        = [nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            break;
        case 2:
            cellExplainText = [addressTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cellText        = [addressArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            break;
        case 3:
            cellExplainText = [infoTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cellText        = [infoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [dateTitleArray release];
    [nameTitleArray release];
    [addressTitleArray release];
    [infoTitleArray release];

    [dateArray release];
    [nameArray release];
    [addressArray release];
    [infoArray release];

    cell.textLabel.text = cellExplainText;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = cellText;
    cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellTextSize = ????????????;
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellTextSize sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return labelSize.height + 12;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(urMaxSize);
CGSize cellSize = [itemName sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]
         constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
return cellSize.height;
}
```

`itemName` is the text u want to fill it with. I guess it is `[infoTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` and corresponding array information based on index. You can get the section also in this method so you can get the string.

If you want to use your method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *cellText;
switch (indexPath.section)
    {
        case 0:
            cellText = [dateTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            break;
        case 1:
            cellText = [nameTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            break;
        case 2:
            cellText = [addressTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            break;
        case 3:
            cellText = [infoTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return labelSize.height + 12;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help so far. I implemented the code you provided me. The above text block. But the dynamic height of the cell isn't changing. I still see the 3 lines/or more of text being squeezed into the standard sized cell. It doesn't take the amount of rows in account. Any suggestions?

Comment: [code](NSString *cellText;
switch (indexPath.section)
{
case 0:
cellText = [dateTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
break;
case 1:
cellText = [nameTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
break;
case 2:
cellText = [addressTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
break;
case 3:
cellText = [infoTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
break;
default:
break;
}
)...

Comment: [code](UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
return labelSize.height + 12;)

Comment: When I do a NSLog check within the switch function it says (null) per case. Somehow it cannot retrieve the data

Comment: try to allocate the string and check. make sure you release it after ur need

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to store in an array your `cellText`/`cellTextExplained` values, so that in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` you can retrieve them:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
     NSString *cellText = [self.cellTextArray:objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     //-- rest of your code here
     UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
     CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
     CGSize labelSize = [cellTextSize sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return labelSize.height + 12;
}
```

Comment: Sorry maybe a really newbie question. I am trying to put the cellText/cellTextExplained into array but I must have a writers block at the moment. How did you suggest me to do this?